# Change spinner list title-bar style

Tags: android

How can i change spinner title bar style.

[image]

I wish to change the title bar for the following items:

```
icon
title style
background color
```

How can i do this?

Comment: this may help [change the spinner title bar][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951203/change-the-spinner-title-bar-style