# change the spinner title bar style

Tags: java, android, title, android-spinner, custom-titlebar

How can i change the spinner title bar style.

[image]

I wish to change the title bar for the following items:

```
icon
title textsize,textColor and
background color
```

How can i do this?

please help me...i have searched google and more sites.am not getting any solution for this.so please let me know its possible.if possible means how can i develop this????please explain me.

**EDIT:**

This is my code:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.row, R.id.country, list);
    spinner.setPrompt("Choose a Status");
  //  spinner.setTextColor("#FF0000");
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

 }
```

Comment: Can you add your source code here so that we can help u

Comment: @S Varun please read my updated question  and give em solution for this.

Comment: try Suraj Bajaj answer it may work for you

Answer (score 2):

**Using Java (Code):**

`spinner.setPrompt("Title")`

OR

**From XML:**

`android:prompt="@string/spinner_title`

[See this to change style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12914526/1581147)

Comment: title is ok.how is change title textColor, title text Size and title background color

Comment: Yes. I saw your code update. You are doing this already. Let me have a look again.

Comment: Give this a try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12914526/1581147
I am not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create CustomSpinner,

To do so try this following way, it works well for me

**Step 1: Create Custom Spinner Class**

```
    class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private int cocktailname; 

        CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor)
        {
            super(context, cursor);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  

          cocktailname = cursor.getColumnIndex(YourDatabase.CK_NAME);  

        }

        @Override
        public View newDropDownView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
        {
             return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dropdownspinnertext, parent, false); 
        }
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinnertext, parent, false); 
        }

       @Override
        public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor)
        { 
                    //Setting the Value here
            TextView paymentname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);    
            paymentname.setTypeface(textFont);
            String cocktail = cursor.getString(cocktailname);
            paymentname.setText(cocktail); 

        }  

     }
```

**Step 2 : Call this Adapter**

```
  CustomSpinnerAdapter custom_spinneradapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this,youcursor);  
  spnListCocktails.setAdapter(custom_spinneradapter); 
  spnListCocktails.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

**Xml for dropdownspinnertext**

I am using Checked Dropdown Spinner

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1" 
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle" 
android:singleLine="true" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:background="@drawable/background_image"
/>
```

**For spinnertext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1" 
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="4dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Hope it helps